# Which microphone does the respondus lockdown browser use?

Tags: browser, microphone

I disabled the microphone of my laptop and there are many virtual microphones. I'd like to know which microphone the respondus lockdown browser uses.

In Google Chrome I selected the virtual microphone of the iVCam software, maybe also the respondus lockdown browser uses the same microphone. The only way in which I can run the respondus lockdown browser is through a button on the webpage of my university; it's not possible to open directly the respondus lockdown browser.